# Mclust function gives error

Tags: r, runtime-error

I try to run a Latent Profile Analysis in R with the package `mclust`. I have four variables, they are continuous (and there are some 0.00). First I say `read.csv2("…")` and then `BIC<-Mclust(data2)`.

Afterwards this error occurs:

> Error in if (loglik > signif(.Machine$double.xmax, 6) || any(!c(scale,  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

My data looks like that:

```
   'data.frame':    219 obs. of  4 variables:  
    $ Var1: num  0.55 0.36 0.09 0.27 1.45 0.45 1.18 3 1.09 0.18 …  
    $ Var2: num  0 0.22 0.33 0.67 0.22 1 1.67 0 2.33 0 …  
    $ Var3: num  0 0 0 0 0 0.38 0 0 0.88 0 …  
    $ Var4: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 …
```

What is wrong here? What am I doing wrong?
I would be very glad if someone could help me.
Thank you

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard for anyone to help you without seeing your data, so consider posting a `dput` or `str` of your data . Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @Tchotchke. I have edited the post.